# Stacking image to parent image?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm new to HTML/CSS, and I've been trying to understand the relative/abstract concept of CSS. What I'm trying to do is stack an image on-top of another image. Provided images show my current layout vs. intentions:
(links direct to images, need 10rep to post `<img></img>`)

Currently:
http://s4.postimg.org/vlf4czqul/example.png

Expectations:
http://s28.postimg.org/k3cdvarp9/intentions.png

My current code is as follows,
HTML:

```
<body style=background:grey">
    <div class="main_container">
        <img id="rounded_shell" src="shell.png" alt="">
        <img id="inner_tab" src="tab_one.png" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html, body{
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main_container{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;

}

img#rounded_shell{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
    z-index: 0;
}
img#inner_tab{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5em;
    max-height: 40%;
    max-width: 40%;
    z-index: 1;  
}
```

I have a main container for everything to fit within, (however I do feel that it can be removed as the `<body>` would theoretically take its place) and within I have the two images, I had thought I'd be able to set the `img#rounded_shell` with a `position: relative` so when I put in the image of the tab, I'd be able to set it to `position: absolute` and have it positioned to the top-left corner of its parent (being `img#rounded_shell` correct?) but it gets positioned as shown above. I also wanted to have them scale proportionately as a group for mobile browsing as well, but I'm assuming that's a different issue on it's own.

Comment: What is your intention for stacking the images? What kind of layout/functionality are you creating? This might help provide a better/more appropriate solution to your question.

Comment: The `rounded_shell` could be considered a background of the `inner_tab`. I have planned for a row of four similair tabs, side by side on both the top edge of the shell and bottom, where each tab will be clickable, so theoretically they'd be buttons.

Comment: A 4x2 arrangement? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/664rLdwd/? Are you trying to fill the entire screen?

Comment: Correct, a 4x2 just like that. So each individual box would consist of a tab_image being clickable and the larger outside box would be the rounded_shell. And no, I didn't want it to fill the screen, I was looking to be able to position dead center of the screen, no matter what device it is being viewed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of our exchange in the comments I'm going to provide an example. This example is all HTML/CSS. It seems to me that a lot of what you're doing doesn't have to be images via an `<img>` tag. Rather than can be a better use of various CSS properties like `border-radius`, `background-color`, `background-image`, etc.

You stated you were new to HTML/CSS so I'm assuming that's why you're going the image route vs the CSS route.

This is what I would do with the info you have provide thus far:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="shell">
    <div class="row top-row">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bottom-row">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The DIVs with the CSS classes of `.row` are not completely necessary. They're mostly there to act as "hooks" for CSS styling and to help you visualize things. The width of `.shell` prevents more than four DIVs appearing in a row so the last four would appear below the first four if we removed the DIVs with the `.row` CSS class.

**CSS**

```css
.shell {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 18px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.shel > .row {
    overflow: auto; /* clearfix */
}
.shell > .row > div {
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* so width/height include border, padding, margin */
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.top-row > div,
.bottom-row > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 0;
}
.top-row > div:nth-child(1) {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
.top-row > div:nth-child(4) {
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.bottom-row > div {
    border-top: 0;
}
.bottom-row > div:nth-child(1) {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
.bottom-row > div:nth-child(4) {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

In the CSS above I used `border-radius` to create curved corners and `background-color` to provide a fill color for the DIVs. I then applied select rules, where appropriate, for individual DIVs and their border settings via the [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo selector. `nth-child()` is supported in IE9+, not sure if that matters or not.

You mentioned that the contents of your *shell* are going to behave like buttons. I don't know what is supposed to happen when one is clicked so ultimately some of the elements might have to be changed, ie `<div>` to `<a>`, or some JavaScript will need to be incorporated. At this point my answer is a basic example and will most likely require you to take additional steps to make it work.

Here is the link to my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/664rLdwd/1/.

Comment: Instead of using `background-color` and `border-radius` you can always use `background` and `background-image` to suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The `absolute` element should be a child element of `relative`. Set the images as a `background-image` of a div or put a wrapper around the back image and wrap the front image.